# anchor tag dynamically inserted with jquery on wordpress not working

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, permalinks

I have this code:

```
$(".div-img").each(function() {

        var maxHeight = 700;
        var imgHeight = $(this).height();

        if (imgHeight > maxHeight) {
            $(this).append('<a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" class="view-full-content view-content external-link fa-external-link-square">View Full Content<span class="crop"></span></a>').find(".cropping-a").css({
                'max-height': '500px',
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'display': 'block'
            });
        }

    });
```

This piece of code insert an anchor tag after a div if the condition is true everything is working but the href part, when I try to click on the anchor tag inserted it sends me to a page with this url `<?php%20echo%20the_permalink();?>`, I already try using a variable but still not working:

```
$(".div-img").each(function() {

        var maxHeight = 700;
        var imgHeight = $(this).height();
        var permalink = $(".view-content").attr("href", "<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>");

        if (imgHeight > maxHeight) {
            $(this).append('<a href="" class="view-full-content view-content external-link fa-external-link-square">View Full Content<span class="crop"></span></a>').find(".cropping-a").css({
                'max-height': '500px',
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'display': 'block'
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: PHP-code does not work in javascript, as this is all handled by the client and PHP is only interpreted on the server

Comment: Do you have this script on a php page

Comment: no @AbhishekVAshok, is not on the php file is on a .js file.

Comment: is the_permalink(); a js function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: no @akr, is not a js function is just the value of an anchor tag just like when you use it on php.

Answer (score 0):

A php tag will only be converted if it is inside a .php page as php is converted by the server into html and server converts only php code inside a php file. Just put the code inside `<script>`tags in a php file or change the file extension to php and put the script inside the `<script>` tags and use `include` to include the file.

**Answer:**

**Method 1**

**Change your page's extension from .js to .php. Then add javascript within the script tags.**

**Your .php (.js file which was changed to .php file) file should look like this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //Text Javascript is not neccessary but it's for some downgraded browsers which have not html5 support
$(".div-img").each(function() {

    var maxHeight = 700;
    var imgHeight = $(this).height();

    if (imgHeight > maxHeight) {
        $(this).append('<a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" class="view-full-content view-content external-link fa-external-link-square">View Full Content<span class="crop"></span></a>').find(".cropping-a").css({
            'max-height': '500px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'display': 'block'
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

**Then to insert the php page to another php page use `include`,`require` or `require_once`**

**Example:**

```
<?php include'path/filename.php';?> // Using Include
<?php require'path/filename.php';?> // Using Require
<?php require_once''path/filename.php';?> // Using require once
```

**When to use include,require and require_once**

The `require()` function is identical to `include()` and `require_once()` except that it handles errors differently. If an error occurs, the include() function generates a warning, but the script will continue execution. The require() generates a fatal error, and the script will stop whereas in `require_once()`
PHP will check if the file has already been included, and if so, not include it again.

**Method Two**

**Copy the script to the php page you want it to be present within the `<script>` tags So your php page should look like:**

```
<?php /* Php codes */ ?>
//Html stylings and tags
<script type="text/javascript"> //Text Javascript is not neccessary but it's for some downgraded browsers which have not html5 support
$(".div-img").each(function() {

    var maxHeight = 700;
    var imgHeight = $(this).height();

    if (imgHeight > maxHeight) {
        $(this).append('<a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>" class="view-full-content view-content external-link fa-external-link-square">View Full Content<span class="crop"></span></a>').find(".cropping-a").css({
            'max-height': '500px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'display': 'block'
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

**You may choose the best method that you want though I recommend method two as it lowers page load time.**

Comment: thank you @Abhishek I'm trying with the first method but give an error Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined and I try as it says here [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) but still not working.

Comment: I fixed the problem of Jquery not defined but now the script is not executing.

Comment: I fixed the problem just change the jquery.js from the footer to the header and now my script is working good, the only problem is that the permalink the anchor tag gets is the url from the first post and that same url assigns it to the rest of divs I don't know how to fix this problem.